# Why template parameter for comparator in priorty_queue instantiation is not asked?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have following code to understand priority queue object instantiation.

```
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<>> int_min_heap;
    return 0;
}
```

The third parameter to the priority_queue template is comparator function. As it can be seen I have used 'std::greater'.

This is compiling successfully, Though I was expecting this to fail the compilation as I have not given paramter to the std::greater i.e. The correct way( as per me) of template instantiation is

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> int_min_heap;
```

I could find any definition of std::greater without input parameter.

Could anyone please point out what I am missing in understanding?

Comment: The template parameter of `std::greater` has a default argument, which is `void`.

Comment: "*I could [not] find any definition of std::greater without input parameter.*" Did you [look for one?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)

Comment: @NicolBolas I checked at [www.cplusplus.com/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/) and that was the source of confusion. I almost always go to cplusplus.com for reference. Now I got reason to check cppreference.com as well. Thanks.

Comment: @user114754: Years ago, cplusplus.com was considered to be the armpit of information about C++. Its information was generally considered either incomplete, inaccurate, or poorly stated. It's best to just avoid the site altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) has a default template parameter since `c++14` which is `void`:

```
template< class T = void >
struct greater;
```

But if this was only a default template parameter, it would fail because you could not call it with two `int`. What happened is that there is a [specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_void) of `std::greater` for void which *"leaves the parameter types and return type to be deduced"* (from [encppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)):

> The standard library provides a specialization of `std::greater` when `T` is not specified, which leaves the parameter types and return type to be deduced.
>
> [`greater<void>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_void) function object implementing x > y deducing argument and return types
>   (class template specialization)

---

Note that without `c++14` both of these fail to compile:

```
// error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1)
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int> std::greater<>>

// error: forming reference to void
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<void>>
```

Comment: On a side note, this should have been done back in 1998.